# TKINTER: Two button with the same functionality but different label listed

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am struggling with creating widgets in classes. I want to create two buttons which run the same code, but I want the label listed to be different. I can't seem to figure out how to use the index properly so the second label doesn't overwrite the first one. Am I missing an obvious mistake?

class Application(ttk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.widgets()

def widgets(self):
    btn_list = [] #List to hold the button objects
    lbl_list = [] #List to hold the label objects

    for i in range(2):
        # Lambda command to hold reference to the index matched with range value
        self.b = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Button #%s' % i, command = lambda idx = i: self.browse_function(idx))
        self.b.grid(row = i, column = 0)

        self.pathlabel = ttk.Label(self, text="HI!")
        self.pathlabel.grid(row=i, column=1)

        self.btn_list.append(self.b) # Append the button to a list
        self.lbl_list.append(self.pathlabel) #Append the label to a list

def browse_function(self, idx):

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select file", filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    self.lbl_list[idx].cget("text").config(text=filename)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What exactly does not work as you want it to? The code seems to save the widgets in the lists correctly. The only thing that seems wrong is that in `self.lbl_list[idx].cget("text").config(text=filename)` you try to use `.configure` on a string. Instead you should use it directly on the Label widget like `self.lbl_list[idx].config(text=filename)`.

Comment: It gives me this error :                                       self.btn_list.append(self.b) # Append the button to a list
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'btn_list'

Comment: the error is obvious - you didn't put `btn_list` and `lbl_list` as a class attribute. Just add `self` to both when you define them as empty lists in the `widgets` method, or better yet create them during the `__init__`

Comment: I think I got it, thank you very much guys. One more question, now that I have on the main window the labels with the file paths, is it possible for a script to use that specific path in its code?(a different script)

Comment: Your `labels` are stored in `lbl_list`. You can loop through them and obtain the label text

Comment: Indeed but how do you loop through them from a totally different script  (literally another .py) ?

Comment: You do it like how you normally import modules. Create an instance of the class `Application`, and get its attribute `lbl_list`